# Syntax of mutate combined with other expressions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm struggling to figure out the corect syntax of mutate combined with other functions. Here I'm trying to remove the text "incubated: " from a column called "days.incubated2"

Any ideas?

```
df%<%
mutate(str_remove(days.incubated2, "[incubated: ]"))
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate(days.incubated2 = str_remove(days.incubated2, "incubated:"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- df %>% mutate(days.incubated2 = str_remove(days.incubated2, "incubated: "))
```

- You had incorrect pipe operator.
- You can add a column name where you want to store the value i.e `days.incubated2` here. (`mutate(days.incubated2 = ....`).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
df$days.incubated2 <- sub("incubated: ", "", df$days.incubated2)
```